# Cannot use immutable annotation with class that has JSON object

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a simple object which I want to make immutable.

```
import grails.converters.JSON

@Immutable
class Response {
    JSON jsonResponse
    int httpStatusCode
    String message
}
```

When I try to compile, i get:

```
| Error Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: Compilation Failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:163)
```

If I do:

```
@Immutable(knownImmutableClasses = [JSON])
```

I get the same.

If I remove the JSON object, everything is fine. So this is where the problem is.  Any ideas?

I am using Grails 2.2.1 and Groovy 2.1.6

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure why you're getting this `NullPointerException` but it doesn't make any sense to mark a class with a `JSON` property as immutable, because `JSON` is not in fact immutable. You can lie to the compiler and pretend it's immutable with `@Immutable(knownImmutableClasses = [JSON])` but this doesn't actually make it immutable.

If you change your class to

```
@Immutable
class Response {
    String jsonResponse
    int httpStatusCode
    String message
}
```

and instantiate it like so:

```
def someObject = [1: 2, foo: 'foo']

def response = new Response(
    jsonResponse: someObject as JSON,
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    message: 'hello'
)
```

that should solve your problem.